# I get a syntaxt error when I try to run the program

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I get a syntax error on the last else statement. This is supposed to be a grade calculator. If someone enters anything that isn't between 0 and 100, then the program should send a message, and then loop until a valid number is entered. Also I am new to programming, so if there is something else wrong with my code, please let me know!

```
number = int(input("Enter the numeric grade: "))
if number > 89:
    letter = 'A'
elif number > 79:
    letter = 'B'
elif number > 69:
    letter = 'C'
else:
    letter = 'F'

print("The letter grade is", letter)
number = int(input("Enter the numeric grade: "))
if number > 100:
    print("Error: grade must be between 100 and O")
elif number < 0:
    print("Error: grade must be between 100 and O")
else:
    # The code to compute and print the result goes here
   number = int(input("Enter the numeric grade: "))
if number > 100 or number < 0:
    print("Error: grade must be between 100 and 0")
else:
     # The code to compute and print the result goes here 
    number = int(input("Enter the numeric grade: "))
if number >= 0 and number <= 100:
    else:
        print("Error: grade must be between 100 and O")
```

Comment: Why do you have the `else:` in there at the end?

Comment: Indentation is very important in Python. See this documentation https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html for if-else syntax in python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I get a syntax error on the last else statement." Okay, so you read and understood the error message. The next step is to understand the code. Instead of asking why the code causes an error, try to *convince me* that it should *not* cause an error. Explain what you intend for it to do, and relate that to the error message. I assume the message said something about indentation, and I assume you know what that means. How do you think the code should be indented, and why? What should happen when `number` is between 0 and 100? What should happen otherwise?

Comment: Also: please only tag your IDE (or other development tools) if you are specifically asking about something related to using them, or if you have a specific suspicion that they are involved in causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is at the bottom, where you've got an empty if statement followed by an else statement, as well as incorrect indenting. From your code, I believe you are trying to use `not`.

I would suggest doing one of two things:
**1.**

```
if not (number >= 0 and number <= 100):
```

**2.**

```
if number < 0 or number > 100:
```

These two pieces of code will both produce the same result.

Also, it seems as though you are repeating the same code several times to try to ensure that the user inputs a number between 0 and 100.  If so, this can be achieved with a while loop.  I've put an example of this below:

```
number = int(input("Enter the numeric grade: "))
while number < 0 or number > 100:
    print("Error: grade must be between 100 and O")
    number = int(input("Enter the numeric grade: "))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The I added the while loop and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

In the last line.

```
if number >= 0 and number <= 100:
else:
    print("Error: grade must be between 100 and O")
```

you didn't write anything after the if statement.
This code will run

```
if number >= 0 and number <= 100:
    print('Write something here')
else:
    print("Error: grade must be between 100 and O")
```

or you can just remove the last if statement its really of no use like try doing something else because there are a lot of if and else statements which don't look nice.
try this:

```
n = int(input())
first = 0
last = 100 
while n < first or n > last:
    print(n,'is not a valid input')
    n = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood, you're trying loop indefinitely until the user input is between 0 and 100.

My solution would be this:

- Define a function that starts by requesting an input from the user.
- Use a while loop that will check if the input is 'correct'. In case the input is not correct, the loop will print the error and call back the function again indefinitely till the user's input is between 0 and 100.
- if the input is between that range, it will then evaluate the grade and return it.

  ```
   def yfunc():
       n = int(input('Enter the numeric grade: '))
       while n < 0 or n > 100:
           print("Error: grade must be between 100 and O")
           return yfunc()
       if n > 89:
           letter = 'A'
       elif n > 79:
           letter = 'B'
       elif n > 69:
           letter = 'C'
       else:
           letter = 'F'
       return letter
   yfunc()
  ```

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.